# Node JS steam-tradeoffer-manager

Tags: javascript, node.js, steambot

I'm working on a SteamTradeBot but I have a problem with `getOffer()`.

```js
manager.getOffer(trade_id[i],function(offer){...});
```

My goal is to output the ID and accept the tradeoffer but it doesn't work because `offer` is set to null.

```
console.log(offer.id);
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing 'error' callback:

```
manager.getOffer(trade_id[i],function(err, offer){...});
```